# What's the right way to add kernel, bias, , activity regularizers with BatchNormalization using tf.keras functional api?

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

Since BatchNormalization comes before Activation, I assume I can't specify activity_regularizers parameter as part of dense layer. Is that correct? Then should I use ActivityRegularization after Activation like this?

```
x = Dense(64, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01))(input)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = ActivityRegularization(l1=0.0, l2=0.01)(x)
...
```